# How to prove that $\sum_{k \neq j} a_kb_ka_jb_j-\sum_{k \neq j} a_k^2b_j^2=2\sum_{1≤k<j≤n}a_kb_ka_jb_j-\sum_{1≤k<j≤n}(a_k^2b_j^2+a_j^2b_k^2)$

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{k \neq j} a_kb_ka_jb_j-\sum_{k \neq j} a_k^2b_j^2=2\sum_{1≤k<j≤n}a_kb_ka_jb_j-\sum_{1≤k<j≤n}(a_k^2b_j^2+a_j^2b_k^2)$$

How to get it?

Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For every family $(z_{k,j})$,
$$
\sum_{k\ne j}z_{k,j}=\sum_{k\lt j}z_{k,j}+\sum_{j\lt k}z_{k,j}=\sum_{k\lt j}(z_{k,j}+z_{j,k}).
$$
In particular, if $z_{k,j}=x_ky_j$, then
$$
\sum_{k\ne j}x_ky_j=\sum_{k\lt j}(x_ky_j+x_jy_k),
$$
while, if $z_{k,j}=x_kx_j$, then $z_{k,j}=z_{j,k}=x_kx_j$ hence
$$
\sum_{k\ne j}x_kx_j=2\sum_{k\lt j}x_kx_j.
$$

Comment: I am commenting late, as I was busy with understanding your answer. Thanks for making me satisfied!!